# Make sure Flex components are loaded at the beginning

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, load, flexbuilder

How can I make sure all the components, even those that are not going to be visible at the beginning, load right away when I start my application?

I  have an application with a ViewStack whose visible child is set via a sidebar menu. Say the ViewStack has two children, A and B. A is initially visible, whereas B is not. How can I make sure they both load at the beginning, so that when I change to B I don't have to wait for it to load?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

each of your viewstacks should have

```
creationPolicy = "all";
```

not sure if this can be set at the application level or not to control all children, but I know it works on viewstacks.

Comment: Well, viewStacks are all I need for now. Thanks.

Comment: I think that's valid for all Flex Containers, since ViewStack inherits that property precisely from the Container class.